# updating array in dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cluster-analysis

i am generating some random points and storing them in a dictionary ....
but **[image: the problem can be seen in the pic with real data points]**

what i need is only points as only lists n not everything ...

i have read many things but cant find any solutions !!!!

please suggest me something!!!!!

here is the code used to update dictionary....

**[image: full code on example points]**

Comment: I'd suggest you give a minimal example input and output because your question is not understandable.

Comment: check it out n suggest something feasible please!!!!

Comment: Please do not post screenshots, post everything as *formatted text*. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). It still isn't clear to me what you need. What does "I want only the points to be in the dicitonary, not everything like above"? Why are you even using `numpy` here? having a bunch of length-2,single dimensional numpy arrays really isn't a good use-case, you might as well use vanilla python data structures, (lists, tuples, etc)

Comment: OMG u will not believe your comment helped me a lot  i just converted the array to a list n it worked ...........

Comment: i was stuck in it for like more than 6 hrs thanks for the help mate ......